# JavaScriptで、split()を使うと、空白が消える。インデント、段落下げを残したい。

Tags: javascript

Chrome上で動作するようにJavaScriptで以下のような実装をし、

```
var lines = text.split( "\n" );
```

行毎に分割しようとしたところ、空白文字が消えてしまいました。
段落下げ、インデントは残したいのですが、どのように修正すれば空白文字、スペース、タブ記号などを正しく扱えるのでしょうか。テキストは、C言語のソースコードです。

Comment: split()は指定していない空白文字を消したりしないはずです。どうやって結果を確認しましたか？

Comment: 元のテキストがどんな内容で、splitにかけた後にどんな内容になるのかを具体的な例も載せてもらうとアドバイスが付きやすいかと思います。

Comment: 皆様ありがとうございます。書き直していただいてなるほど、質問の文章らしくなって、感謝してあります。元のテキストは、解凍ソフト、Ｚ７のプログラムファイルです。どうも、一度クリアしたテキストエリアに、データか残っているなど、よくわからない、のです。バイナリエディタがないので、文字コードがスペースか、ｔタブなのかもわからないので、一文字読み込んで処理、　してみます。単語に切り出す、もくてきもあるので、、、皆様ありがとうごさいます。